# Command to give a prefilled chest of items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I `/give` a chest that has items already inside of it? I know you can do it because of mcDungeon, but I can't seem to get it to work whenever I try it myself.

Minecraft version 1.9.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `BlockEntityTag` compound holds potential tile data for the item's tile entity variant. For example, the following provides a chest that has 1 stone in the first slot of the chest when placed:

```
/give @p minecraft:chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:"minecraft:stone",Count:1b,Slot:0b}]}}
```